# How to limit download time in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How to limit download time in ios?
I need :
if download time from url to ImageView more than 2 second, download from another url.

Comment: This is a very vague question. Give us more specifics. How are you doing your downloads? Are you using NSURLSession? If so, it's easy to change the timeout on a request. (Should also be easy for the now-deprecated NSURLConnection, though I haven't tried, seeing as how it's deprecated and all...)

Comment: Please read the guide to asking good questions, and take it to heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the timeout to a shorter time, 2 seconds:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.timeoutInterval = 2.0
```

[Timeout reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLRequest/timeoutInterval)

Answer (score 0):

If you download images asynchronously, you can use this method (together with if):

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(numberInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print("Delayed job")
}
```

So if numberInSeconds is 2, the code will execute after 2 seconds.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question. He's asking how to make a download time out after a short time and attempt to download from another URL, not delay a download.